# You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: php, laravel, apache

i created project on Laravel and i setup my project in hosting. But i cant see pictures in my website. when i check the error i got this "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." how can i fix this?

here is my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

 # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

 # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  </IfModule>
```

i use SSL sertification for my website. and i created middleware HttpsProtocol.
here is my HttpsProtocol code

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->secure() && App::environment() === 'production') {
        return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

and i use this middleware in my routes/web.php

here is my web.php route

```
Route::get('/posted-cvs', 'PostedCvsController@index')->middleware(HttpsProtocol::class);
```

i dont know how to fix this problem. website is works but when i select posted-cvs category i cant see there users picture

Comment: Please use standardard grammar & punctuation. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask]

Comment: @philipxy A lot of posters here are not native English speakers. You can cut them some slack on their command of the grammar, I think!

Comment: @BenHillier I agree with your sentiment. I very much doubt that I thought this person was not a native speaker when I cut-&-pasted that comment. If I had I would have dropped the 'grammar'. I think it is clear that this person chose to punctuate poorly. Maybe their first language is texting.